# How to replace a pattern except specific pattern with another pattern in a column?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a data frame(x) with "Symbol" column, which I want to replace (all "-*" with "") but I don't want change some values such as: 1-Mar, 1-Sep, 1-Dec,...

```
x<-data.frame("ID"=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"),"Symbol"=c("3-Mar","STON1-GTF2A1L","1-Dec","NME1-NME2","12-Mar","TNFSF12-TNFSF13","8-Mar","TMEM189-UBE2V1","10-Sep"))
```

I tried this code: `x$Symbol<-gsub ("-*", "", x$Symbol)`
But it changes (1-Mar, 1-Sep, 1-Dec)

I need the below data frame

```
x<-data.frame("ID"=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"),"Symbol"=c("3-Mar","STON1","1-Dec","NME1","12-Mar","TNFSF12","8-Mar","TMEM189","10-Sep"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
x$Symbol <- sub("-(?!(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Ju[nl]|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)$).*", "", x$Symbol, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J5UmOh/1)

**Details**

- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?!(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Ju[nl]|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is an abbreviated month name at the end of the string (**NOTE**: if you may have any more text after the month name use `(?!(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Ju[nl]|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\\b)` (to match month names as whole words) or `(?!Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Ju[nl]|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)` to just match the names as non-bounded substrings)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/5Pklru):

```
df<-data.frame("ID"=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"),"Symbol"=c("3-Mar","STON1-GTF2A1L","1-Dec","NME1-NME2","12-Mar","TNFSF12-TNFSF13","8-Mar","TMEM189-UBE2V1","10-Sep"))
df$Symbol <- sub("-(?!(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Ju[nl]|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)$).*", "", df$Symbol, perl=TRUE)
df
```

Output:

```
  ID  Symbol
1  a   3-Mar
2  b   STON1
3  c   1-Dec
4  d    NME1
5  e  12-Mar
6  f TNFSF12
7  g   8-Mar
8  h TMEM189
9  i  10-Sep
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `paste` "18" in `Symbol` and see if it parses to a `Date` and `sub` the values which are not dates.

```
df$Symbol <- with(df, ifelse(is.na(as.Date(paste0(Symbol, "-18"), "%d-%b-%y")), 
                   sub ("-.*", "", Symbol), Symbol))

df
#  ID  Symbol
#1  a   3-Mar
#2  b   STON1
#3  c   1-Dec
#4  d    NME1
#5  e  12-Mar
#6  f TNFSF12
#7  g   8-Mar
#8  h TMEM189
#9  i  10-Sep
```

First ran

```
df$Symbol <- as.character(df$Symbol)
```

to convert `Symbol` into characters.